# Encoding problem: Convert bytes to Chinese characters in R

Tags: r, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I read from a html file in R which contains Chinese characters. But it shows something like

```
"    <td class=\"forumCell\"><a href=\"#\" onClick=\"if(confirm('\xc4\xe3\u0237\xd0\xc5Ҫ\xbbָ\xb4\xb8\xc3\xce\xc4\xd5\xc2\xc2\xf0\xa3\xbf')){location.href='articleBakAdmin.php?action=restore&articleID=120516';}\">\xbbָ\xb4</a></td>"
```

It is the "\x" strings that I need to extract. How can I convert them into readable Chinese characters?

By the way, somehow simply copy and pasting the above \x strings would not replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure they are all chinese characters? what is the html page encoding? the strings you pasted looks to be a mix of hex `\xc4\xe3` and unicode chars `\u0237`.

Comment: That’s right... R told me that I had a mix of hex and Unicode. But when I check with ‘isUTF8’ it returns yes.

Comment: How can I check the encoding of the website?

Comment: if you use chrome browser, you can open up DevTools via `F12`, then load the website and type `document.charset` into the console. This should give you the encoding of the current document.